# My validation accuracy is stuck and training accuracy is decreased continuously

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I am new to working with LSTM models, but I have a small network. I have extracted MFCC features from my audio files and have flattened it and given as input. But the validation accuracy is stuck between 2 values and my accuracy is decreasing continuously.
I have used RMSprop with a learning rate of 0.001.
I have tried changing Optimizer, adding dropout, and batch normalization.
The dataset is evenly balanced also.

```
Model: "model_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 3460, 1)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
cu_dnnlstm_1 (CuDNNLSTM)     (None, 3460, 1024)        4206592   
_________________________________________________________________
cu_dnnlstm_2 (CuDNNLSTM)     (None, 1024)              8396800   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 512)               524800    
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, 512)               2048      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 256)               131328    
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (Batch (None, 256)               1024      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 257       
=================================================================
Total params: 13,262,849
Trainable params: 13,261,313
Non-trainable params: 1,536
_________________________________________________________________




Train on 385 samples, validate on 165 samples
Epoch 1/10
385/385 [==============================] - 61s 160ms/step - loss: 1.0811 - accuracy: 0.5143 - val_loss: 0.6917 - val_accuracy: 0.5273
Epoch 2/10
385/385 [==============================] - 55s 142ms/step - loss: 0.7536 - accuracy: 0.5169 - val_loss: 0.6980 - val_accuracy: 0.4727
Epoch 3/10
385/385 [==============================] - 55s 142ms/step - loss: 0.7484 - accuracy: 0.5039 - val_loss: 0.7002 - val_accuracy: 0.4727
Epoch 4/10
385/385 [==============================] - 55s 142ms/step - loss: 0.7333 - accuracy: 0.5091 - val_loss: 0.7030 - val_accuracy: 0.5273
Epoch 5/10
385/385 [==============================] - 55s 142ms/step - loss: 0.7486 - accuracy: 0.4675 - val_loss: 0.6917 - val_accuracy: 0.5273
Epoch 6/10
385/385 [==============================] - 55s 142ms/step - loss: 0.7222 - accuracy: 0.4935 - val_loss: 0.6917 - val_accuracy: 0.5273
Epoch 7/10
385/385 [==============================] - 55s 143ms/step - loss: 0.7208 - accuracy: 0.4883 - val_loss: 0.6919 - val_accuracy: 0.5273
Epoch 8/10
385/385 [==============================] - 55s 142ms/step - loss: 0.7134 - accuracy: 0.4805 - val_loss: 0.6919 - val_accuracy: 0.5273
Epoch 9/10
385/385 [==============================] - 55s 143ms/step - loss: 0.7168 - accuracy: 0.4987 - val_loss: 0.6927 - val_accuracy: 0.5273
Epoch 10/10
385/385 [==============================] - 55s 143ms/step - loss: 0.7089 - accuracy: 0.4909 - val_loss: 0.6926 - val_accuracy: 0.5273
```

Here is my code:

```
def build_model():
input = Input((20*173,1))
x = Conv1D(filters=16, kernel_size=4, activation='relu')(input)
x = AveragePooling1D(pool_size=2)(x)
x = Conv1D(filters=16, kernel_size=3, activation='relu')(x)
x = AveragePooling1D(pool_size=2)(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = keras.layers.Reshape((13808, 1))(x)
x = CuDNNLSTM(1024, return_sequences=True)(x)
x = CuDNNLSTM(512)(x)
x = Dense(256,activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.3)(x)
x = Dense(128,activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.3)(x)
x = Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=x)
return model
reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_accuracy', factor=0.2,patience=3, min_lr=0.001)
opt = RMSprop(lr=0.0001)
m2 = build_model()
m2.compile(loss = "binary_crossentropy", metrics=['accuracy'],optimizer = opt)
m2.fit(X, y, batch_size=16, epochs=10, validation_split=0.3,callbacks = [reduce_lr])
```

Comment: please post the code you've written.

Comment: Check this one, it might help.
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/49807/training-accuracy-decreases